# Question on square matrices with certain properties

Tags: matrices

The below question had been asked in one of the competitive exams. It seems like all the statements are true after taking some examples and solving them. But can we come up with some proof to show that all the statements 1,2 and 3 are true.

Q) Let A be an n×n invertible matrix with real entries whose row sums are all equal to c.Consider the following statements:

1. Every row in the matrix 2A sums to 2c.
2. Every row in the matrix $A^2$ sums to $c^2$.
3. Every row in the matrix $A^{-1}$ sums to $c^{-1}$.

   ```
   Which of the following is TRUE?

   A) none of the statements (1),(2),(3) is correct
   B) statement (1) is correct but not necessarily statements (2) or (3)
   C) statement (2) is correct but not necessarily statements (1) or (3)
   D) statement (1) and (2) are correct but not necessarily statement (3)
   E) all the three statements (1),(2),and (3) are correct
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\...\\1\\\end{pmatrix}$$

gives a column vector each of whose entries is the row sum, $r$ say.

Then 
$$2A\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\...\\1\\\end{pmatrix}=2\begin{pmatrix}r\\r\\...\\r\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2r\\2r\\...\\2r\\\end{pmatrix}.$$

$$A^2\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\...\\1\\\end{pmatrix}=A\begin{pmatrix}r\\r\\...\\r\\\end{pmatrix}=rA\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\...\\1\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}r^2\\r^2\\...\\r^2\\\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}r\\r\\...\\r\\\end{pmatrix}=A^{-1}A\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\...\\1\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\...\\1\\\end{pmatrix}$$ and therefore

$$A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\...\\1\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}r^{-1}\\r^{-1}\\...\\r^{-1}\\\end{pmatrix}.$$